# Passing parameters between bound events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have two bound events - a click and a hashchange as per below (super-simplified example):

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e) {
    location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
}

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

How would I pass the id of the element raising the click event to the bound hashchange event?
I've seen examples like the below, but can't get it working:

```
$('a').bind('click', ['some-data'], function(e) {
    location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
}

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data[0]);
}
```

Any advice would be great...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to find the anchor that initiated the hash change from inside the `hashchange` event handler, because the event is fired by `window` itself.

Inside the `hashchange` handler you can inspect the value of `location.hash` though, because you previously put the anchor's id in there using `location.hash = $(this).attr('id')`.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {
    console.log(location.hash.substr(1)); // should be the id of your anchor
}
```